# Using Jquery when using Bower

Tags: jquery, bower

I have started to learn bower..

Isn't it better to use [jQuery with a CDN](https://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn) even when we use bower in an application ? So what Bower will it be useful for in such as case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason people use bower is to stay upto date of library version. 
If we see performance wise using cdn is more effective.
Read this discussion for more info https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/19

Comment: Thanks but i don't see that Bower can manage itself CDNs which i think it's supposed to do.

Comment: The most bower can do is  add cdn field in .json file .so that if file is unavailable it loads file from cdn.
{
  "name"        : "jquery",
  "version"     : "1.8.1",
  "main"        : "./jquery.js",
  "cdn"         : "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js",
  "dependencies": {
  }
}

Comment: Priority had to be given to the cdn to be loaded first as it would be faster and anyway i don't understand in which cases any source would be unavailable :)